# MySql - Get rows based on matching ids

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with the next step of my query, my mind is completely drawling a blank here….I have 3 MySql tables.

The first table is called post and has an id column (there are other columns, but they are not relevant)

```
Id    Title    
----  --------
1      A
2      B
```

The second table is called followingPost (posts users like) and it has an id column, userid column and postid column

```
Id    userid    postid
----  --------  -------------------
1     1         2
3     2         1
```

The third table is called postTags (tags for the posts) and this has an id column, postid column and tagid column.

```
Id    postid      tagid    
----  --------    --------
1     2           1
2     1           1
```

Get Users Liked Posts, which I have done with the following

```
SELECT *
FROM followingPost
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = followingPost.postid
WHERE userid = 14
```

And Then Get Users Liked Posts with Tag IDs, , which I have done with the following

```
SELECT *
FROM followingPost
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = followingPost.postid
INNER JOIN postTags ON posts.id = postTags.postid
WHERE userid = 14
```

No what I am trying to do is take the tags of the post the user liked and get all the posts that also have the same tag id.

This is what I am expecting:

```
    Id    Title    
    ----  --------
    2      B
```

I am expecting this because user 1 likes post 2 and post 2 has tag of 1 and so does post 1, so I am expecting to return post 1

Any ideas on how to accomplish the final step?

I really hope this makes sense, please let me know if you need me to clear anything up.

Comment: Please add some example data that would be contained within the table and the expected output you are wanting. Optionally add the data you are receiving that is not the output you desire.

Comment: This that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from posts
left join postTags on posts.id = postTags.postid
where postTags.tagid in
 (SELECT postTags.tagid
 FROM followingPost
 INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = followingPost.postid
 INNER JOIN postTags ON posts.id = postTags.postid
 WHERE userid = 14) 
and posts.id not in 
 (SELECT posts.id
 FROM followingPost
 INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = followingPost.postid
 INNER JOIN postTags ON posts.id = postTags.postid
 WHERE userid = 14)
```

Comment: This returns the correct results, but the post 1 (title A) appears in the results, I do not want to include post the user already likes.